# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "address" violates not-null constraint

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

When I create a Location instance, i get this error. 
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "address" violates not-null constraint`

this is my locaiton model.

```py
class Location(DirtyFieldsMixin, TimeStampedModel):

    id = SmallUUIDField(
        default=uuid_default(),
        primary_key=True,
        db_index=True,
        editable=False,
        verbose_name='ID'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

the payload looks like this when posting a locaiton.

```py
{'name': 'Beij the Sage', 'address': None, 'latlon': None, 'timezone': 'America/Los_Angeles', 'phone': '', 'email': ''}
```

i have `blank=True` for the model so having `None` for the value of `address` shouldn't throw this error.

Answer (score 8):

`blank=True` only controls form-level validation. You're getting an error at the database validation layer, because the field defaults to `null=False`. To save empty values, you have to add `null=True` to the constructor kwargs.

```
address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: remember to rerun make migrations once you update your model :)